# ToListAsync freezing UI

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, async-await

I have a model called Patient:

```
[Key]
public Guid Id { get; set; }
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }
```

My repository to return all patients (the row count is 1):

```
public async Task<List<Patient>> GetPatientsAsync()
{
    //await Task.Delay(1).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return await _context.Patients.ToListAsync();
}
```

Running that code freezes the UI, how ever if I remove the comment inside the GetPatientsAsync(), the UI is responsive while it returns all patients (again, only 1 row).

On my ViewModel end I'm calling it like so:

```
public async Task LoadPatients()
{
      var s = await _repository.GetPatientsAsync();
      //if (Patients != null) SelectedPatient = Patients.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Any clue why this is?

Thanks

Comment: Where is `LoadPatients` being called from?

Comment: It's being called from the the View, through a Behavior, look at my post below about solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So I solved the problem, I'm using the CallMethodOnLoadBehaviour.cs. Since this Behavior isn't executing as a `await Task` it's blocking the UI.

What I had to do to get around this was the call to the repository to `GetPatientsAsync` I wrapped inside a `Task.Run(() => _repository.GetPatientsAsync());`.

If there is a better way to use reflection and able to call `await <Task>`, please let me know!

```
public class CallMethodOnLoadBehavior : Behavior<FrameworkElement>
{
    #region Properties
    public string MethodName
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(MethodNameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MethodNameProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MethodName.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MethodNameProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MethodName", typeof(string), typeof(CallMethodOnLoadBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public object TargetObject
    {
        get { return GetValue(TargetObjectProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TargetObjectProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for TargetObject.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TargetObjectProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("TargetObject", typeof(object), typeof(CallMethodOnLoadBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(null));
    #endregion

    #region Methods
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.Loaded += OnLoaded;
    }

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (AssociatedObject == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(MethodName) || TargetObject == null) return;
        var minfo = TargetObject.GetType().GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredMethod(MethodName);
        if (minfo == null) return;
        minfo.Invoke(TargetObject, null);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try marshaling your property assignment back on to the UI thread. I'm not sure how EF works. My gut tells me `ToListAsync()` is lazy loaded, meaning when you call `FirstOrDefault()`, the returned value is fetched from a background thread still (because you await the call in the repository) and you try to assign and call `OnPropertyChanged` on the main thread.

```
public async Task LoadPatients()
{
      var s = await _repository.GetPatientsAsync();
      if (Patients != null) 
      {
          var patient = Patients.FirstOrDefault();
          Application.Dispatcher.Current.Invoke(() => SelectedPatient = patient);
      }
}
```

Comment: This isn't the case, when I step through the code, I clearly see a long pause right after I call .ToListAsync(). Also disabling ProxyGeneration and LazyLoading before the query doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Neither does marshaling it back to the UI?

Comment: So this is my actual code:         `public async void LoadPatients()
        {
            Patients = await Task.Run(() => _repository.GetPatientsAsync());
            if (Patients != null) SelectedPatient = Patients.FirstOrDefault();
        }` This works because I wrap my async getpatients in a task.run. see my answer below for more details on how exactly I'm calling LoadPatients.